# Print BST Preorder in Windows Form label

Tags: c#, winforms, label, binary-search-tree, inorder

Probably a *super easy question*, but I have no idea how to do with Forms.

I need to call a Preorder traversal method (implemented in another class) in a Winform's code, so that the Preorder is printed in a label the Form interface.

So I have a BST class, where there's a method for traversing the tree in Preorder. There's also a method for inserting a value to the tree. Like so:

```
namespace BinaryTree //the BST's class
{
   public partial class BinarySearchTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable<T>
   {


public void Insert(T value) //method for inserting
    {
       ....
    }

public IEnumerable<T> Preorder() //method for Preorder traversal
    {
        List<T> preOrdered= new List<T>();
        if (_value != null)
        {
            preOrdered.Add(Value);

            if (LeftChild != null) //
            {
                preOrdered.AddRange(LeftChild.Preorder());
            }

            if (RightChild != null) //
            {
                preOrdered.AddRange(RightChild.Preorder());
            }
        }
        return preOrdered;
    }
}
```

Now, to use these operations I have a Windows Forms interface. It has code for **Creating** new tree, for **Adding value** to the tree (by typing value in inputTextBox and clicking btnCreate) and **Show the tree** to the user (via PaintTree), but I need to also **print the tree's Preorder to the user** (in a label in the interface for example).

Say I have a label in the interface called "PreorderLabel" for this; this is where **I want the Preorder to be printed**.

The Forms's code looks like this:

```
namespace BinaryTree
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private BinarySearchTree<int> _tree;


    void PaintTree()
    {
        if (_tree == null) return;
        pictureBox1.Image = _tree.Draw();
    }




    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _tree = new BinarySearchTree<int>(new BinarySearchTreeNode<int>(int.MinValue));
            PaintTree();
        }

        catch(NotImplementedException) { MessageBox.Show("There is no implementation!"); }
    }


    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var val = int.Parse(inputTextBox.Text);  //makes a variable out of the input value from the user, to work with
            if (_tree == null)
                btnCreate_Click(btnCreate, new EventArgs());
            _tree.Insert(val);  //***calls the "Insert" method from the BST class, to insert the value to the tree
            PaintTree();  //shows the user the tree

//**this is [I guess] where I need code for printing the tree in Preorder**
           PreorderLabel.Text = ???????

            inputTextBox.SelectAll();
            this.Update();
        }

        catch (Exception exp) { MessageBox.Show(exp.Message); }
    }
```

So, as the user clicks the Add button (btnAdd), not only shall the Insert method be called by the tree "_tree", and the PaintTree method be called to show the tree; but also the Preorder method be called to **print the Preorder in the label "PreorderLabel"**.

How would this be done?

I'd be super happy for all help!

Comment: The preorder traversal method code is shown in the first code paste? Or?

Comment: Well, it's not *super easy question* mainly because it's unclear what do you mean by **print** in **label**. Label is just a static text, what really do you want to **print** there?

Comment: Sorry. I'm thinking about something like changing the "label.Text" to a string of the Tree nodes in preorder each time the user adds a value, that's what I would like to print there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)` method with a delimiter string like below:

```
PreorderLabel.Text = String.Join("; ", _tree.PreOrder().Select(item => item.ToString()));
```

The `PreOrder()` method will return `IEnumerable<int>` instance so what we need to do is only convert `int` values to `string`.